# Como alterar a linguagem do Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Se você seguir o passo a passo de instalação do Visual Studio 2017, ele instala a linguagem do sistema operacional. Como alterar a linguagem para inglês?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

A instalação do Visual Studio 2017 tem várias linguagens além do inglês e, por padrão, instala a linguagem do sistema operacional.

Se você precisar instalar uma linguagem diferente, você deve:

1) abrir novamente o instalador e selecionar modificar/modify
[image: Tela]

2) Selecione pacotes de idiomas e depois os idiomas que deseja instalar
[image: Tela de instalação]

3) Depois feche o instalador, abra o Visual Studio e altere o idioma em:
Ferramentas -> Opções -> Ambiente -> Configurações internacionais [conforme sugestão do Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/189389/35280).

[image: Tela do VS]

Solução achada [na resposta do Change language of Visual Studio 2017 RC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40710202/3424212)

Answer (score 8):

Quando eu instalei ele perguntou quais linguagens eu queria, talvez pelo fluxo que escolhi de configurar antes.

Se quiser ainda pode mudar indo em: Options -> Environment -> International Settings

[image: Troca de linguagem no Visual Studio]

Se não instalou a linguagem precisa chamar o instalador novamente e escolher a linguagem que deseja. Aqui:

[image: Instalação de pacote de linguagem]

Answer (score 0):

Instalei apenas o idioma em português, mas precisei instalar o idioma inglês, tive dificuldade em encontrar a solução para meu problema, apesar de ser simples.

Resolvi - abrindo painel de controle -> visual studio -> modificar (ao abrir o instalar novamente coloquei na aba idioma e escolhi inglês e coloquei para instalar).

Espero ter ajudado alguém!